# RiskPortfolio Package Optimal Portfolio results

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

I'm trying to use the  RiskPortfolios package to find the optimal portfolio weights for a couple of different optimizations, with long only and weights sum to 100% constraints.

Using the sample data provided with the package as an example (given below), I am getting portfolio weights that are all ~0% for all securities.

```
library("RiskPortfolios")
data("Industry_10")
rets = Industry_10
covEstimation(rets)
Sigma = covEstimation(rets)
optimalPortfolio(Sigma = Sigma, control = list(type = 'maxdiv', constraint =  'lo'))
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RiskPortfolios/versions/2.1.7/topics/optimalPortfolio

results:
[1] 1.596802e-03 4.426586e-02 5.115952e-21 1.829356e-01 9.853242e-18

[6] 1.092012e-01 1.528876e-01 1.821066e-01 3.270063e-01 4.557049e-21

Does anyone have any experience with this package or info on where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The weights will sum to 1 (i.e. 100%). For instance, 4th weight is `1.82e-01`, i.e. 18.2%.

Comment: Thank you, not quite sure how I failed to see that but you are correct.